# Jquery slider is not working on body load

Tags: jquery

I have site http://elitereviewtheme.com/amazon/test/ on which i customize the slider. But problem is that slider is not working on load & even there is no error in the code. If click on any thumbnail or next prev button, then it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the carousel is a paid for one so you should probably contact rivaslider via their support OR you can try this:

After you setup the slider call this and it should auto start:

`setTimeout($('.rs-next').click(), 100);`

Comment: i already tried this one but it is not working

Comment: @inderpreetsingh try it inside a setTimeout so that you can be sure it has loaded.

Comment: thanks for you help, i am near to it.
i put this code
setTimeout("autoplay()", 2000);
function autoplay()
{
alert("g");
$('.rs-next').click();
}

but problem is that not working without alert

Comment: Try calling it on window load instead of document load. That event fires later.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer to help others in the future!